# USB data cable is not detected

Tags: 14.04, usb

The USB data cable is not detected in my Ubuntu 14.10 computer

The output of `lsusb` is

```
praveen@praveen-Lenovo-B590:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0294 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Which data cable? What do you want to connect?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Are you talking about `SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade` ? Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question to improve the clarity, as this will help us to help you. As it is I can only guess what you are talking about. Guessing is not a productive use of time.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be detected. `lsusb` lists only connected devices.

Comment: lsusb shows lists of connected device im plug my pendrive or data cable is shown in the list but not its not show the partition